# Unknown Top level operator $exists

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

This is my query:

```
var que=Query(Criteria.where("name").exists(true).`isEqualTo`("Technographics"))
mongoTemplate.exists(que,"collectionname");
```

It throws

```
UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 2: 'unknown 
top level operator: $exists' on server localhost:27017. The full 
response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: 
$exists", "code" : 2, "codeName" : "BadValue" }
```